# XML input for a RESTful web service

Tags: java, web-services, rest

I have an xml input file from the following URL,

> http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=new%20york%20&%20sensor=false;

i would like to read the latitude and longitude positions from the XML file and i intend to write a method in the RESTful web service which calculate the location with minimum distance from each other.

i am very new to web services but i am aware that i should write my logic within the GET method and the @consumes and @produces will be XML.

i need some help to understand how should i pass the XML to the web service.
Should i use JDOM to extract the value from the requires tag and pass it as a parameter to the web service ?

need some help !

Answer (score 0):

HTTP GET method won't work here since you need to send some data in the payload. You can use POST method which allows you to send a message body.

Comment: I appreciate your help ! but i dont want to access the database, it will be sufficient to do the computation within the webservice class and return the the result in a XML format. Pls correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: You were mistaken, need to send the coordination as the request payload. No need to keep it in the database.